# Can we add Owner comments as an Answer

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

When I was visiting this

[Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in php 5.6.25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377340/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect-in-php-5-6-25)

I found that the question owner got a solution to that question before answering and owner mention this in its comments.

I copied it and post As an answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47438635/2723943

As well as mentioned also.

I want to ask it is right or should I delete my answer.

Comment: You should either make your answer a community wiki or ask the OP to write an accepted self-answered answer. Otherwise posting the quoted comment as your answer doesn't make much sense, as the solution isn't yours, but you'll be earning the reputation for it.

Comment: and how make make answer a community wiki

Comment: I make my answer a community wiki